# AlarmClock just once,every year at specific day at specific hour

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am interested in android development and i want know if it is possible play some song every year at specific day at specific hour in android and how to do it. Thank you!

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this , MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 02);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 55);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every year


}
```

}

Broadcast:

```
    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Received.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will help you - `https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html` and `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , NotifyService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisApp.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, YOUR_HOUR);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 31556952000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every year
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me what i am doing wrong? See edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to learn how to set an alarm.

As for your specific goal, you can set a new alarm for the next year when the current one rings.